# Iterating through functions with Service Calls in Angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 functions calling services to generate an image gallery.

First function get items in the gallery and the second function is just to get the base64 string for the thumbnail image.

My thought process is, once the gallery data is returned successfully, I then iterate through the items running the loadthumbnail for each item and passing its value into the model.

Issue Im finding is that i always get a value of UNDEFINED returned. Im not sure but it might be that its not allowing a pause for the service to return its data so is immediately adding a value of undefined?

Functions are

```
loadTemplates(id: number) {

this.loadingTemplates = true;

this.dataService.getTemplates(id).subscribe((res: any) => {

  this.loadingTemplates = false;
  this.templates = res;

  for (let template of this.templates) {
    template.thumbnail = this.loadThumbnail(template.id);
  }

}, err => {
  this._modalService.openErrorToast('Error ' + err.status + ': ' + err.statusText, 'Error');
});
  }

  loadThumbnail(id: number) {

this.dataService.getThumbnail(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
  console.log("data:image/png;base64," + res.Value);
  return "data:image/png;base64," + res.Value;

}, err => {
  this._modalService.openErrorToast('Error ' + err.status + ': ' + err.statusText, 'Error');

  return "hi";
});
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Value` property actually exists on the response object from the server?

Comment: maybe just return "data:image/png;base64," + res; or "Value" with small letters

Comment: HI, i can see in chrome network console the data is there for the returning value and it is held inside .Value. I think the for loop is executing without considering the primise for the subscription so its accepting undefined instead of waiting.